# Is there any limit as to how many VoIP push can be sent in any given time?

Tags: ios, swift, pushkit

I would like to use VoIP push in one of my apps. I am using it for regular notifications as well. I was wondering if Apple puts any limit to how many VoIP push can be sent in any given period of time?

Answer (score 0):

- No there isn't any limit for sending voip push to a device, bcz whatsapp,imo etc do the same way, and i havent faced a single problem for receiving voip calls.
- So it means you can send as many pushes as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Once our server ran into a bug that sending VoIP push every second to my app. 
My app was rapidly filled by thousands of push records in the log in a few hours.

So I think the answer is no.

Maybe this is the reason that apple limited PushKit in iOS13: any VoIP app can abuse VoIP push as they want.